# Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно расставить знаки препинания в этом предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Хорошее образование(,) конечно(,) не помешает(,) но(,) может быть(,) и не поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Хорошее образование (,) конечно (,) не помешает (,) но (,) может быть
> (,) и не поможет.

Очень много запятых... По-моему, лучше будет читаться такой вариант:

***Хорошее образование, конечно, не помешает — но, может быть, и не поможет.***

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!